# Django simpleJSON jQuery.parseJSON invalid label

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json, simplejson

I have the following view in django

```
def playingNow(request,playlist_id):
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    sql =   "SELECT id, timestamp, song_played_id, playlist_from_id, now() - timestamp as timepassed FROM music_song_played \n"\
            "WHERE playlist_from_id = %s \n"\
            "ORDER by timepassed ASC \n"\
            "LIMIT 1;"
    cursor.execute(sql,[playlist_id])
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    songPlaying = get_object_or_404(song, id = data[0][2])
    playing = {}
    playing["song"] = unicode(songPlaying)
    playing["licensed"] = "Licensed by "
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(playing), content_type ="application/javascript; charset=utf8")
```

and the following template

```
{% block content %}

<script type='text/javascript' src='/media/inthebackground-utils.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/media/jwplayer/swfobject.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/media/jwplayer/jwplayer.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/media/jquery.periodicalupdater.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = new Object();
</script>


  <div id="StationName">Your Listening to: {{ station.name }} </div>
  <div id="playingNow-{{ station.name }}"></div>
  <div id='padder{{ station.name }}' style="height:20px; float left"></div>
  <div id='mediaspace-{{ station.name }}'"><p> You dont have adobe flash player installed. Please download and install from <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer">here</a> </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    data.{{ station.name }} = {'userid':'{{ user.pk }}', 'playlist' : '{{ station.pk }}'};

    $.PeriodicalUpdater('/music/playingNow/{{ station.pk }}/',
                    {method: 'get'}, 
                    function(remoteData, success, xhr, handle)
                    {

                      jQuery.parseJSON(remoteData);
                      console.log(typeof(remoteData));
                      console.log(remoteData);
                      licenceDiv = '<div id="licence">'+remoteData.license +'</div>';
                      songDiv = '<div id="licence">'+remoteData.song +'</div>';
                      contDiv = '<div id="playingNow-{{ station.name }}">' + songDiv + licenceDiv +'</div>';
                      $('#playingNow-{{ station.name }}').replaceWith(contDiv);
                      jwplayer('mediaspace-{{ station.name }}').play(true);
                     });

    jwplayer('mediaspace-{{ station.name }}').setup({
      flashplayer: "/media/jwplayer/player.swf",
      file: "{{ station.url }}?{{ cacheBuster }}",
      height: 20,
      width: 300,
      controlbar: "bottom",
      provider: "sound",
      duration: "0",
      events: {
        onPlay: function(event){play(data.{{ station.name }});},
        onPause: function(event){pause(data.{{ station.name }});}
        }
     });

     $(window).unload( function () { pause(data.{{ station.name }} ); } );
  </script>


{% endblock %}
```

when the [periodicalUpdater](http://www.360innovate.co.uk/blog/2009/03/periodicalupdater-for-jquery/) fires and does a get, it gets the json as a string from the view function, which means I can access it like a normal json structure. And when I try to do the jQuery.parseJSON firefox firebug throws an "invalid label" error. I've read in a few places that this can be because jquery is expecting is expecting JSONP instead of JSON. but im not sure how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
...
$.PeriodicalUpdater('/music/playingNow/{{ station.pk }}/',
                {method: 'get',
                 type: 'jsonp'}, 
                function(remoteData, success, xhr, handle) ...
```

That should tell the ajax call to use jsonp instead.

Note: As a disclaimer, I haven't actually used this library but I investigated this because I'm interested in a jQuery auto-updater myself. Looking at the docs here:

https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/

we can see that it uses the regular jQuery Ajax call and you can specify parameters to PeriodicalUpdater that then get passed into the Ajax call. The `type` field in PeriodicalUpdater appears to be equivalent to the `dataType` field in the jQuery ajax call whose docs are found here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: cheers i'll check it out. As a side note, although I havent used PeriodicalUpdater in anger yet, it works pretty well in dev so far. I've yet to see how much load comes from lots of clients, but It seems like a pretty good implementation overall.

Comment: gave it a go, unfortunatly this didnt solve the issue. I Still get the invalid label error.

Comment: What does the data returned from the server look like? Using jsonp, I believe it should come back as a valid javascript object and you don't even need to parse it. See this thread for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543513/how-to-parse-jsonp-data-returned-from-remote-server