# Dealing with JSON result

Tags: javascript, json, api, foursquare

I'm having trouble reading the JSON data from a venues search. Here is my code:

```
xmlhttpRC = new XMLHttpRequest();
url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll="+pointStrr+"&oauth_token=V5PI2GJ0KDOVH2GAHNHJ5DVLMRKNF440FR1N1HPG0XHX2OBQ&v=2015643&
callback=JSONP";
xmlhttpRC.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttpRC.onreadystatechange = recCb;      
xmlhttpRC.send(null);
//return recommendedArr;
}

function recCb(data){
//console.log(data);
if(xmlhttpRC.readyState == 4){
    if(xmlhttpRC.status == 200){
        var recRes = xmlhttpRC.response;

        console.log(recRes);

        //console.log(recRes);
        console.log(recRes.meta.code);
    }
}
```

}

I get the reponse I expect from the server, and firebug shows me that a JSON object is returned, but I am not sure how to access the data inside from here.

console.log(recRes.meta.code) returns the error:

"recRes.meta is undefined"

Where am I going wrong?
I want to access the venues information but I am just using meta.code as a simple test.
This is probably really simple but I'm stumped!

Thanks in advance,
Ross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var decodedResp = JSON.parse(recRes);
if (decodedResp.meta.code === ...)
```

JSON-object is just a representation of an JS-object, see; it should be parsed first.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys. using JSON.parse(recRes) gives the error: JSON.parse: unexpected character. DO you think its because the JSON data starts with JSONP?

Comment: JSONP is a bit of another story, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543513/how-to-parse-jsonp-data-returned-from-remote-server)

Comment: I have requested it as JSON now and it is returned as JSON(...
But I still get the error:
JSON.parse: unexpected character


var recResD = JSON.parse(recRes);

Comment: Hmm... may be you'd get a better understanding what's wrong with a response by using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Ah indeed, "Parse error on line 1:
JSON({    "meta": {
^
Expecting '{', '['"
Is there anything I can do about that, considering that is foursquare's response?

Comment: Great, so we're dealing with JSONP-object after all, not json string. Didn't you try to drop the 'callback' param completely, btw, from your Foursquare request?

Comment: I changed it to callback=JSON. Will try and get rid of callback parameter but I think I read that that returns XML. Will let you know in a second.

Comment: Anyway, if that's unavoidable, you just have to put some processor function into your code somewhere (which will work with a JS object, not JSON), then just eval the response from Foursquare within handler function.

Comment: oh that seems to have worked :) one last question - when accessing the first venue, where do i put the [0] in the following: recResD.response.groups.items.venue.name?
Cheers for you help by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse JSON. Modern browsers have JSON.parse built in, older versions of IE etc. do not - you can theoretically use eval(response) but it creates a security hole.

[There is a library](http://www.json.org/js.html) to parse it if you cannot depend on users having modern browsers.

Comment: I'd comment the below but I don't have enough rep to yet. can you post out the hierarchy the JSON data is being returned as?

Comment: sorry mate only just seen this. problem solved by removing &callback=JSONP. thank you for you input. is there any way I can give you rep?