# How to deal with json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, facebook-graph-api

I was retrieved (response) object like this

```
{
"data": [
{
  "name": "Let's go angular!",
  "start_time": "2015-12-05T11:30:00+0200",
  "id": "908575145894907"
},
{
  "name": "يوم دراسي: \"تقنيات البث الإذاعي و الفضائي\"",
  "start_time": "2015-10-21T10:00:00+0300",
  "id": "1640694736210572"
},
{
  "name": "الحفل الختامي لنشاطات النادي الهندسي",
  "start_time": "2015-10-20T11:00:00+0300",
  "id": "906776472735155"
},
{
  "name": "The challenge of handling Big Data",
  "start_time": "2015-03-17T09:30:00+0200",
  "id": "1489359784617992"
},
{
```

how could I deal with this using javascript?

Comment: google for "how to deal with json" and you will get plenty of results, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422372/dealing-with-json-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = {
"data": [ { "name": "Let's go angular!", "start_time": "2015-12-05T11:30:00+0200", "id": "908575145894907" }, { "name": "يوم دراسي: \"تقنيات البث الإذاعي و الفضائي\"", "start_time": "2015-10-21T10:00:00+0300", "id": "1640694736210572" }, { "name": "الحفل الختامي لنشاطات النادي الهندسي", "start_time": "2015-10-20T11:00:00+0300", "id": "906776472735155" }, { "name": "The challenge of handling Big Data", "start_time": "2015-03-17T09:30:00+0200", "id": "1489359784617992" }]};


for(i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++)
  {
    document.write("name: " + json.data[i].name + "<br>");
    document.write("start_time: " + json.data[i].start_time + "<br>");
    document.write("id: " + json.data[i].id + "<br><hr>");

  }
```

and @Sergio is right it a good practice to do this to avoid an errors in response.

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: @YassirAwad if it's an answer on your question so mark it as answer please

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are receiving a [JSON string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON). If its a string you should parse it, otherwise use it as it is. To parse it do:

```
var object = JSON.parse(response);
// or do: var object = typeof response == 'string' ? JSON.parse(response) : response;
```

and then

```
var data = object.data; // which is a array
```

and you can reach what you need by its keys... like:

```
alert(data[0].name);
alert(data[1].name);
```

#### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/vabpko52/

Comment: var object = JSON.parse(response);its not work but when i make loop just like under answer its work,thank you.

Comment: @YassirAwad test the commented line with var object = typeof response == 'string' ? JSON.parse(response) : response;