# Sanitizing a string into JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I'm web scraping and the website on get request returns an string like this:

```
jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051({"d":[{"__metadata":"cool"}]})
```

The whole code is here:

```
var baseUrl = "http://SOMEURL.COM?spatialFilter=nearby(52.47952651977539,-1.911009430885315,400)&$select=*&$top=200&$format=json&key=AjF8l9J6TH-WM5tkfFYdYE8NVUx9SFe4ya9aBaxKFFPBImvFWWHPOsRMSBesWblU&jsonp=jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051&_=1429532300821%20HTTP/1.1";

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,
        loadPlugins: false
        }
});


var fs = require('fs'),
    shopInfo,
    savePath, 
    date = new Date(),
    secondsNow = date.getSeconds(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    minute = date.getMinutes();
    month = date.getMonth() + 1, 
    fname = 'virginmedia-'+month+'-'+day+'-'+minute+'-'+secondsNow+'.txt';

function saveToFile(finalData) {
    savePath = fs.pathJoin(fs.workingDirectory,
     'output',fname);
    fs.write(savePath, finalData, 'w');

}


casper.start(baseUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }});
casper.then(function getData(){


    var rawData = this.getPageContent();

    shopInfo = rawData;
        shopInfo = shopInfo.replace("jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051(",'');
        shopInfo = shopInfo.replace(/\)$/,'');
        shopInfo = JSON.parse(shopInfo);
    var resultPack = shopInfo.d.results;

    var finalData = resultPack.map(function(val){
    return [
              val.Latitude,
              val.Longitude,
              val.EntityStoreName
           ];
    });

    saveToFile(JSON.stringify(finalData)); 
    casper.echo("\n Hello! I just returned " + finalData.length
    + " shops");

});
casper.run();
```

In other words valid json inside a function call!. But I need the JSON part.

Inside browser I could easily makeup a function with the same name that returns its own parameters:

```
function jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051() {
  return arguments[0];

}
```

But in casperjs it just doesn't work. So my last option was using regex to get out the JSON string:

```
shopInfo = shopInfo.replace("jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051(",'');
shopInfo = shopInfo.replace(/\)$/,'');
```

Is there any better way to do it?

**Edit 1 :** 
From comments I found out that it's actually JSONP, and not JSON and life got easy! I found my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543513/how-to-parse-jsonp-data-returned-from-remote-server) after searching for JSONP instead.

**Edit 2 :** 
Another solution found in the comments: by changing the request, the website returns proper JSON on its own!

Comment: What does "it just doesn't work" exactly mean?

Comment: You're getting JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: i believe JSONP returns json with a function call like that

Comment: Can we see how you are getting the JSONP, and what you intend to do with it?

Comment: `shopInfo.substring(shopInfo.indexOf("(") + 1, shopInfo.lastIndexOf(")"));`

Comment: @zerkms I mean I spent a long time on it and couldn't get it working. And I think there must be better ways to get that done, which other comments showed that there are.

Comment: @adeneo thanks alot for letting me know. I was googling for JSON all the time, and I got no where. Now that I know it's JSONP life is easy, I found this question to be matching my situation exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543513/how-to-parse-jsonp-data-returned-from-remote-server

Comment: @Amadan I'm not sharing because I have no idea about the legal issues attached to scraping!

Comment: @Omid: I meant share the code that fetches the JSONP; feel free to anonymise the address. Many frameworks will have explicit support for JSONP, and seeing the code might make it obvious how to handle it more nicely.

Comment: what could be an alternative to SO, where you can freely ask stupid questions without getting -1? With this one I think I'll be banned and I should find another place!

Comment: Notice in the URL that you have `jsonp=jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051`? I don't know the site, but if you leave that part out it is possible they will serve pure JSON and not JSONP. (Also, there's millions of people who read StackOverflow; one person decided you should be downvoted? Who cares? Ignore and truck on.)

Comment: @Amadan now I feel both stupid and ignorant :D Yes removing the parameter did it. Well the problem is SO has warned me that if others don't like my questions I'll be banned! Last time I couldn't ask anything for 48 hours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments, here's the answer:

1. That format is called JSONP, or JSON with padding. It's discussed in SO in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543513/how-to-parse-jsonp-data-returned-from-remote-server)
2. There's actually no need to go that way, the HTTP request can be changed so that it returns true JSON data. Just remove this part from the request:   `jsonp=jQuery18305426675335038453_1429531451051&_=1429532300821%20HTTP/1.1`